# Display Django time variable as full hours, minutes am/pm

Tags: python, html, django

I want to use a time variable instead of a CharField for a model, which displays multiple saved times. My issue is it displays as "9 am" instead of "9:00 am", and "noon" instead of "12:00 pm".
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Relevant code below-

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
time=models.TimeField()
free=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
player1=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 1")
player2=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 2")
player3=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 3")
player4=models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Player 4")

def __str__(self):
    return self.time
```

HTML

```
 <h7>{{post.time}} &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="{% url 'update0' post.id %}"  class="btn-sm btn-success" >Update</a></h7>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by just using the built-in template datetime format like so:

`{{ post.time|date:"h:i A" }}`

This will display the datetime as: *09:00 AM*. You can read more about this in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Answer (score 5):

You can try using built in `date` template tag.

```
{{ post.time|date:'H:i A' }}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, nothing displays at all with that.

Comment: Edit- I've just realised the "j" in your answer is probably just a typo, and you would have been on the money! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it was. Sometimes I got confused with another signs and I didn't notice.